# AngularJS: How to sync an http call with a variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http

I'm trying to do a general function inside a controller which gives me the data from the backend and assign this data to a variable.

I have made this code, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
self.getData = function(url){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get(url)
    .success(function(data){
        deferred.resolve(data);
        console.log("Total profiles: " + data.data.length);         
    })
    .error(function(error){
        //do something
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};

$scope.data = self.getData(ServiceURL.url[7]);
console.log("Total profiles inside function: " + $scope.data.length);
```

The call to the function works fine and give the total of profiles correctly, but when I try to assign this data to $scope.data it doesn't work fine because when I try to show the total of profiles with console.log("Total profiles: " + $cope.data.data.length) I've got the next exit:

**Total profiles outside function: $scope.data: undefined**

Furthermore, the execution is not synchronized, because first try to show the value of $scope.data and then the value from backend.

How can I synchronize this call and assign correctly the exit of the function to the $scope.data variable?

Is there any way to do what I want with a service? I'm trying to do it but $q variable always was undefined, and I don't know how to pass correctly. Do you have any example that works fine?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ONE OPTION**

is to assign your $scope.data within your return call from self.getData().
Like this:

```
$http.get(url)
    .success(function(data){
        deferred.resolve(data);
        $scope.data = self.getData(ServiceURL.url[7]); //Here is it.
        console.log("Total profiles: " + data.data.length);         
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your example ... self.getData is the call to http.get and in your example you call self.getData inside your http.get call ... I'm lost ...

Comment: No, you can't. The success() function will run as a callback with the response from the server. Outside the success() scope, the data will be garbage collected. :/
BTW, take a look at the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) docs, the syntax of .success() have changed to .then() both for success and error callbacks.

Comment: Thank you!!! I understand!!! But I've got another question ... Imagine ... that I have several calls to backend to show data to the same page. Is it possible that there is any problem because I initialize several times $scope.date, one per call. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes, I do. Add me aí que eu can show to you some code of mine doing something like that. And [this is me](https://plus.google.com/u/0/106194671661676502809).

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just set $scope.data within a function, then call the function like.

```
  function getProfiles(){
    $http.get(url).success(response){
        $scope.data = response;
     } 
  getProfiles();
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work to me. Outside the function $scope.data is undefined!!! And I don't know why ,,,